# Troubleshooting installing Xcode updates, stuck

Tags: macos, xcode, mac-appstore, install

I am trying to install the upgrades to Xcode, Xcode version 7.2. Unfortunately, the App Store shows that this installation has been "Installing --- less than a minute" for over four hours.

It appears to be stuck. How can I fix this? Why is this happening?

I tried correcting the permissions for Xcode, running

```
$sudo pkgutil --repair com.apple.pkg.Xcode
```

I get this in return:

```
Verifying files from package 'com.apple.pkg.Xcode' on '/'.
    ACL found but not expected on 'Applications'.
    Unable to set owner & group on "Applications". Error 1: Operation not permitted
    Unable to set permissions on "Applications". Error 1: Operation not permitted
```

Can I try to install these upgrades via the Terminal? I am using OS X El Capitan 10.11.2

Comment: While on one machine, update went through in minutes, others took around 3-4 **hours**, all while progress showed around 1-3 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my recent experience (this morning).

Downloading Xcode7.2 without going through the App Store is a waste of time and can give problems later. Best to delete all previous attempts.

Log onto your Apple Developer account.
Look for Xcode 7.2 and download this dmg. You will be asked to agree to new Apple agreement. The download is 4.5GB +, so it may take awhile. In Berlin with a 100Mb line, it still took 18+ minutes for me.

Once the dmg is fully downloaded, double click on icon in your Downloads directory (don't click on any previously downloaded xcode7.2 dmg)

The splash screen requires you to drag Xcode into Applications. If you are asked whether to replace a newer version - keep your wits about you. If you have previously downloaded xcode7.2 outside of the App Store envelope, it may be 'more recent'.

The copy from Download directory to Applications directory will take time. Expanded, the file size is 9GB+

---

You may also want the new command line tools. There are two versions depending on what version of OS X you are using.

Have fun

Comment: Basically, I had to do this. I deleted XCode and downloaded again from the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

For command line you could try using:

`sudo softwareupdate -l` (to list all available updates)

`sudo softwareupdate -ai` (to install updates)

`sudo softwareupdate --help` (for other help options)

Answer (score 1):

On my machine, it would not start until I deleted the version in applications. Then the download started.